# Gradle maven-publish : task to publish only one

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-publish

I have a Java project that build and publish many jars (**a.jar**, **b.jar**, ...) using :

```
publishing {
    publications {
        a (MavenPublication) {
            artifactId 'a'
            artifact aJar
        }
        b (MavenPublication) {
            artifactId 'a'
            artifact aJar
        }
    }
}

repositories { ...
```

I have also define a **z.jar** and I want a special task to publish it and I want to not build / publish it for the build and publish (publishToMaven*) tasks.

How can I define this kind of task ?

I try something like that and other variant and it failed to compile the gradle :

```
task zPublish(type: PublishToMavenRepository) {
    publication = new MavenPublication() {
        artifactId 'z'
        artifact zJar
    }
}
```

I search [in the source](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/maven/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/publish/maven) of **maven-publish** plugin without success.

Thanks for a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating separate tasks

```
publishing {
    publications {
        a (MavenPublication) {
            artifactId 'a'
            artifact aJar
        }
        b (MavenPublication) {
            artifactId 'b'
            artifact bJar
        }
        z(MavenPublication) {
            artifact zJar
        }
    }
}

task zPublish() {
    dependsOn('publishZPublicationToMavenRepository')
    description('Publishes Z')
}

task otherPublish() {
    dependsOn('publishAPublicationToMavenRepository', 'publishBPublicationToMavenRepository')
    description('Publishes A and B')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Gradle plugin `maven-publish` creates a conventional task per publication and repository, so if you define your publication then you can publish it using that conventional task.

For example if you have defined a `z` publication you can then use task `publishZPublicationToMavenRepository`.

Comment: But I want to exclude publishZPublicationToMavenRepository when I call "publish", "publishToMavenLocal", "publishToMavenRepository".

Comment: Then you can just run `publish -X publushZPublicationToMavenRepository`. `-X` will exclude given task from execution plan.

Comment: My team use the Eclipse gradle plugin, so the easy way is to double-click on a task without arguments.
My current workaround is to disable publishZPublicationToMavenRepository by default and active it manualy when I need it.

Comment: Well, there are some means Gradle offers OOTB check related documentation page out https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html?_ga=2.92866522.65684940.1496735759-1476385789.1486043396#sec:skipping_tasks